# Windows 10 Administrator group members lost their rights

Tags: windows-10, ntfs, uac

On a windows 10 laptop Administrators group memebers, (except one) lost their administrator rights. Meaning cannot access file system even those that are allowed for Users.

Effective rights shows full access, however cannot run / open / edit files. "Run as administrator" does not work as well. Newly created users struggle the same issue.
SFC and CHKDSK has no effect - no troubles found.

The most perculiar thing of all - booting in Safe mode there is no issue - meaning - Admionistrator group members have the same rights as they should. Booting normal - the issues persists.

I am out of ideas and desperately crying for help.

Comment: What occurred before this issue? Windows Update? Network changes? Security changes, e.g., AV update or Group Policy changes? You need to do some trouble-shooting at your end, e.g. examine logs looking for when the issue began and what updates occurred.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik thanks for the reply. Lot of updates installions, that's for sure. I did not log with any other user rather than 1st one for a long time.I've checked logs, found nothing suspicious, I also set up audit rule and see success audit while trying to open file but the error message / access denied message afterwards.

Comment: @Sharper - [Edit] your question with the  relevant information.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: As this happened after a "Lot of updates installations", it might be too complicated to analyze what went wrong. I suggest to [Do a Repair Install of Windows 10 with an In-place Upgrade](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/16397-repair-install-windows-10-place-upgrade.html) to bring everything to a known and coherent state.